# Windows ReadDirectoryChangesW() -- Handle duplicated events

Tags: windows, winapi, pywin32, inotify, pywin

I'm monitoring directory changes in Windows with Python win32 module. The task is to capture `CREATE`, `DELETE`, and `MODIFY` events for both files and directories recursively in a specified directory. NotifyFlag is set like this:

```
FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE
```

The problem is duplicated events may be return and I can't figure out why, for example, a simple modification on file will result in 3 file update notifications -- exactly, two sets of notifications issued: the first set contains only 1 update notification and the other 2 -- all on the same file.

Also, any approach to eliminate duplicated events?

Thanks and Best regards!

Comment: You need to store a tuple of <name, timestamp> in a map and check each. If a margin of error is OK, you can store the hash of the name instead.

Comment: Does this happen for every editor? It could just write/edit in chunks rather than a single write of all the data.